# Decreasing for loops in Python impossible?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I could be wrong (just let me know and I'll delete the question) but it seems python won't respond to

```
for n in range(6,0):
    print n
```

I tried using xrange and it didn't work either. How can I implement that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using this for anything? It's rather uncommon to need this functionality!

Comment: @katrielalex I use it to iterate over a matrix from right to left. is there a different way you suggest I should do it?

Comment: you could try `for i in reversed(mat):` although that might be slower

Comment: Please take a look at [Print a list in reverse order with range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286365/print-a-list-in-reverse-order-with-range), It offers some other helpful information.

Comment: Please take a look [Print a list in reverse order with range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286365/print-a-list-in-reverse-order-with-range), the accepted answer explains it very clearly.

Comment: @Katriel This is handy for creating a list of rectangles in Tkinter using `x0, y0, x1, y1` tuples where the top of rectangle (`y0`) is greater than the bottom (`y1`). I haven't coded it yet but I believe this question has merit for that purpose and up-voted it as a consequence.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

```
for n in range(6,0,-1):
    print n
# prints [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Betcha OP actually wanted `range(5,-1,-1)`. Although he could probably figure that out from trial and error.

Answer (score 57):

This is very late, but I just wanted to add that there is a more elegant way: using `reversed`

```
for i in reversed(range(10)):
    print i
```

gives:

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: What's elegant about that? You spend time reversing a list instead of generating it the way you want it.

Comment: @alexis it doesn't cost anything. You get `reversed(range)` for free because of the nice [`range_reverse`](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L151) optimization built into CPython. I did some quick benchmarks and couldn't find a significant cost difference between `step=-1` and `reversed()` in both Python 2.7 and 3.3. Also please note that [this idiom is used in heapq](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/heapq.py#l179).

Comment: Thanks, @kojiro, that's interesting. But unless you used `xrange` in your Python 2.7 tests, `reverse` will be operating on an ordinary, already-generated list, not on a range object; so are you saying _any_ list can be efficiently reversed, or just `range/xrange` objects? (the heapq code you link to involves a Python 3 range object).

Comment: @alexis I wouldn't be so bold as to suggest that any list can be efficiently reversed – that's too unqualified a statement for me to answer anyway. It's telling, though, that the heapify code changed from `step=-1` to `reversed()` between Python [2.3](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.3/Lib/heapq.py#l168) and [2.4](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.4/Lib/heapq.py#l175)

Comment: `reversed(range(10))` can't possibly output `4` through `0`. Perhaps you meant `range(5)`?

Answer (score 15):

```
for n in range(6,0,-1)
```

This would give you `6,5,4,3,2,1`

As for

```
for n in reversed(range(0,6))
```

would give you `5,4,3,2,1,0`

Answer (score 3):

```
for n in range(6,0,-1):
    print n
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> range(6, 0, -1)
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

0 is conditional value when this condition is true, loop will keep executing.10 is the initial value. 1 is the modifier where may be simple decrement.

```
for number in reversed(range(0,10,1)):
print number;
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but for anyone tasked with creating their own or wants to see how this would work, here's the function with an added bonus of rearranging the start-stop values based on the desired increment:

```
def RANGE(start, stop=None, increment=1):
    if stop is None:
        stop = start
        start = 1

    value_list = sorted([start, stop])

    if increment == 0:
        print('Error! Please enter nonzero increment value!')
    else:
        value_list = sorted([start, stop])
        if increment < 0:
            start = value_list[1]
            stop = value_list[0]
            while start >= stop:
                worker = start
                start += increment
                yield worker
        else:
            start = value_list[0]
            stop = value_list[1]
            while start < stop:
                worker = start
                start += increment
                yield worker
```

Negative increment:

```
for i in RANGE(1, 10, -1):
    print(i)
```

Or, with start-stop reversed:

```
for i in RANGE(10, 1, -1):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Regular increment:

```
for i in RANGE(1, 10):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Zero increment:

```
for i in RANGE(1, 10, 0):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
'Error! Please enter nonzero increment value!'
```

Answer (score 0):

For python3 where `-1` indicate the value that to be decremented in each step

`for n in range(6,0,-1):
    print(n)`