# Python loop out of order

Tags: python, loops

The code shown below:

```
for count in range(0, 5):
    print(count)
```

The output will be:

0
1
2
3
4

The question is
Is it possible to iterate in Python out of order:

Something like this:

```
for count in range(5, 0):
    print(count)
```

the output:
4
3
2
1
0

Comment: if you ve time please read the usage of range,                       
    range([start,] stop[, step]) -> list of integers

Comment: Use `reversed(range(0,5))`.




source: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286365/print-a-list-in-reverse-order-with-range-in-python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286365/print-a-list-in-reverse-order-with-range-in-python

Comment: by "out of order" , do you mean random ?

Answer (score 3):

> range(start, stop[, step])

It accepts the third parameter `step`

So you can do this way:

```
for count in range(4, -1, -1):
    print(count)
```

Comment: True only for python2.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Also works in python3. https://www.dropbox.com/s/btdp3tw6035ylh4/Screenshot%202013-12-30%2000.30.47.png

Comment: `range` returns a list of integers in python3? Really?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7286465/1798187) will help:

```
for x in reversed(range(5)):
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reversed()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) to inverse the order of values in iterator:

```
for x in reversed(range(5)):
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
l = range(0, 5) 
random.shuffle(l)
for count in l
    print count
```

Answer (score 0):

RANGE produces APs(Arithmetic Progressions).
In this case the step size is negative.

You can specify step size by:

```
range(Start of series, End of series [, Step size])
```

Thus here we use:

```
for counter in range(4, -1, -1):
    print counter
```

End of series is always 1*(step size) less than the value passed to range.

NOTE:

```
reversed(range(...))
```

Can also be used, but its efficiency is lower compared to the above method.
Additionally many other manipulation functions do not work with reversed() yet.