# How do I print out everytime the state of the list every time you make a pass in bubble sort?

Tags: list, python-2.7, sorting, for-loop, bubble-sort

I have a question on how to get the following output in python 2.7.

```
>> bubble(['abe','Ada','bak','bAr'], False)
['Ada', 'bak', 'bAr', 'abe']
['bak', 'bAr', 'Ada', 'abe']
['bAr', 'bak', 'Ada', 'abe']
>> bubble(['Adm','abe','bAr','bak'], False)
['Ada','bAr','bak','abe']
['bArt','bak','Ada','abe']
```

The input for the functions are the following.
A list of strings (L) and a Boolean value which represent ascending alphabetical order (asc=True) or descending alphabetical order (asc=False). In both cases, it is in dictionary order. I want to print out the state of the list every time there is a pass.

```
def bubble(L, asc):
  n = len(L)
  if asc == False:
    for i in range(1,n):
      for ii in range(n-i):
        if L[ii].upper()<L[ii+1].upper():
          tmp=L[ii]  
          L[ii]=L[ii+1]
          L[ii+1]=tmp
    print L
  if asc == True:
    for i in range(1,n):
      for ii in range(n-i):
        if L[ii].upper()>L[ii+1].upper():
          tmp=L[ii]  
          L[ii]=L[ii+1]
          L[ii+1]=tmp
    print L
```

In addition, can I replace the way I am currently accessing item of list to `i-1` and `i` and not `i`,`i+1` ?

Comment: do you mean replace  way you accessing   item of list  ( access as `i-1,i` and not `i,i+1` )  ?

Comment: Yes. That is what I want to do, but I don't how to do it. I tried different ways but it doesn't seem like it goes through the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

Print it after the inner loop gets over.

```
def bubble(L, asc):
   n = len(L)
   if asc == False:
      for i in range(1,n):
        for ii in range(n-i):
            if L[ii].upper()<L[ii+1].upper():
                tmp=L[ii]  
                L[ii]=L[ii+1]
                L[ii+1]=tmp
        print L
  if asc == True:
    for i in range(1,n):
        for ii in range(n-i):
            if L[ii].upper()>L[ii+1].upper():
                tmp=L[ii]  
                L[ii]=L[ii+1]
                L[ii+1]=tmp
        print L
```

For the second part of your answer, you can use your inner loop to be

`for ii in range(n-1,i,-1).` // This runs the loop in reverse order.

```
      for i in range(1,n):
            for ii in range(n-1,0,-1):
                if L[ii-1].upper()<L[ii].upper():
                    tmp=L[ii-1]  
                    L[ii-1]=L[ii]
                    L[ii]=tmp
```

You meant this, right?

Comment: Thank you so much. This help me a lot. Your explanation before the code helps.

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I don't want to reverse the order of the loop. I have rephrase my question to make it better. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Have Updated the answer. Check if you meant the same thing.

Comment: @R.Yamada : Does it seem fine?

Comment: Yes. The code works fine. I also want to get the following output. However, with the code currently it doesn't give the same output.  >> bubble(['Adm','abe','bAr','bak'], False)
['Ada','bAr','bak','abe']
['bArt','bak','Ada','abe']

Answer (score 1):

Use feature of range method which allow you to iterate in reverse order

```
print range(1,3) # [1,2]
print range(3-1, 0, -1) # [1,2]
```

By the way you can avoid code duplication of loops ( `if asc == False` and `if asc == True` remove conditions).

To do it use function below(i've added comments):

```
def bubble(L, asc=False):
   n = len(L)
   # passing -1 as lest argument of range is allow to iterate in reverse order
   for i in range(n-1, 0, -1):
       for ii in range(n-1-i, 0, -1):
           # you assign boolean value which depends on `asc` param to comparison_result
           comparison_result = L[ii-1].upper() > L[ii].upper() if asc else L[ii-1].upper() < L[ii].upper()
           # check bool of comparison_result 
           if comparison_result:
               tmp=L[ii-1]
               L[ii-1]=L[ii]
               L[ii]=tmp
   print L


print bubble(['1', 'a', 's'])
```

Line

```
comparison_result =  if asc else L[ii-1].upper() < L[ii].upper()
```

is equivalent of:

```
if asc:
   comparison_result = L[ii-1].upper() > L[ii].upper()
else:
   comparison_result = L[ii-1].upper() < L[ii].upper()
```

Comment: Thank you. Your description is really easy to understand. I have learn more about python programming.

Comment: @R.Yamada You are welcome :) Hope that was use full for you ! Also, you can take a look on my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286365/print-a-list-in-reverse-order-with-range-in-python/35977481#35977481 , it contain description particularly for getting reversed array with  `range` method :) Have i nice day!

Comment: When I try to run the program, I have a error. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'comparison_result' referenced before assignment. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @R.Yamada that'a mean you are trying to use variable, before some value assigned to it. You can take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855493/referenced-before-assignment-error-in-python it has more  explantions ...