# Fast Algorithm for partial sums on a list

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I have been learning Python for 2 months now. In order to hone my programming skills, I solve problems on *Codewars* from time to time.

#### Task

[Codewars kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5ce399e0047a45001c853c2b):

> Write a program that takes a list of numbers as an argument and return a list of partial sums.

#### My Attempt

I wrote a solution that I tested and it works:

```
def parts_sums(ls):
    length=len(ls)+1
    def gen():
        for elt in range(0,length):
            yield sum(ls[elt:])   
    
    result= list(gen())
    return result
```

Codewars is rejecting this solution because it's **too slow** for lists with thousands of numbers.

I have spent an embarrassingly huge amount of time trying to come up with a faster solution with no avail.

How can the algorithm be designed more performant?

Comment: Wouldn't we spoil the pleasure of other people who like a puzzle, by posting a solution here?

Comment: I am not looking for an explicit solution...As a beginner, I am sure I am unaware of many algorithms that generally solve problems like these faster...I am looking for a direction to learn this type of algorithms and eventually solve this problem

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe this: You are summing over same elements every time. How about working from end to beginning and using the previous result?

Comment: *Partial sum* is too vague. What is requested is called the *suffix sum*.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with an explicit loop:

```
result= ls + [0]
for i in range(len(result)-1, 0, -1):
  result[i-1]= result[i] + result[i-1]
```

Note that it can also be done in-place in `ls`.

Comment: What are the "boosting" constructs here in terms of performance? I guess: (a) the _explicit_ (ranged for) loop (compared to while or recursion), (b) the pre-sized list which's elements are just reassigned (compared to extending a list with `append`, `+ or list-comprehension).

Comment: @hc_dev: in the first place, O(n) instead of O(n²).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to compute the sum of a slice at each step, all you have to do is subtract one number from the previous sum.

Here's a pretty naive but straight forward solution, subject to further optimizations.

```
def part_sums(ls):
    result = [sum(ls)]
    for x in ls:
        result.append(result[-1] - x)
    return result
```

Comment: What about `[p for p in np.cumsum(ls)][::-1]`? Or are we not allowed to use `numpy`?

Comment: @CutePoison I'm pretty sure using a library function that does everything is not in the spirit of the exercise.

Comment: Agreed, its a fine balance - one could argue, that `sum` does some (no pun intended) of the calculations as well

Comment: @CutePoison also your solution is wrong :p

Comment: ooh.. yeah. Was a bit too fast there! But the question still persist tho ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by *Yves Daoust*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71064027/fast-algorithm-for-partial-sums-on-a-list/71064431?noredirect=1#comment125623939_71064027), seems like a **suffix sum** array with additional zero-element (as sum over empty array).

#### Suffix Sum

Some notes on [Suffix Sum](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/guided-paths/data-structures-algorithms/content/118820/offering/1382369):

> Given an **array ‘A’ of size N**, its *suffix sum* array is an array of the **same size N** such that the ith element of the suffix sum array ‘Suffix’ is the sum of all elements of the given array till ith index from the end, i.e Suffix[i] = A[i] + A[i+1] + A[i+2] + … + A[N-1] - (0-Based indexing).

> For Example:
> Given A[] = [3, 4, -1, 2, 5], the suffix sum array S[] is given as - S[0] = 13, S[1](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/guided-paths/data-structures-algorithms/content/118820/offering/1382369) = 10, S[1](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/guided-paths/data-structures-algorithms/content/118820/offering/1382369) = 6, S[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) = 7, S[5] = 5.
>
> i.e. S[] = [13, 10, 6, 7, 5]

See also:

1. Dev.to (2020): [Prefix Sum & Suffix Sum - Programming Tools](https://dev.to/grekz/prefix-sum-suffix-sum-programming-tools-1eh5)
2. Wikipedia: [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) (might be related, not sure)

#### Implementation

Following approach uses these concepts for performance:

- predefined, fix-sized result array (instead of extending or list-comprehension)
- fix-sized loop `for i` (instead of recursion) to reverse increment
- explicit fast-returning if-branch for inputs with 0 or 1 elements

```
def suffix_sum(arr):
    result = arr + [0]   # add the zero as last element for this task (copied input)

    n = len(arr)
    if (n <= 1):  # input with 0 or 1 elements returned as is
        return result

    last = n-1  # the last of the input array stays unmodified 

    # iterate by element (last to first):
    for i in range(last, -1, -1):  # step backwards from last to first
        result[i] = result[i+1] + arr[i]   # result-sum = previous-sum + element (increases with each element)

    return result
```

Results for 3 test-cases:

```
in: [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
out:[20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]
in: []
out:[0]
in: [1234]
out:[1234, 0]
```

Notes:

- The reverse-for-loop using a `range` as in [Print a list in reverse order with range()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286365/print-a-list-in-reverse-order-with-range)
- the *first* element is denoted by `-1` as second range-argument

Debug-print each iteration with `print(f"{i:2}: {result[i]} = {result[i+1]} + {arr[i]}")` shows 4 iterations for example-input `[0, 1, 3, 6, 10]` with length `n=5`:

```
 3: 16 = 10 + 6
 2: 19 = 16 + 3
 1: 20 = 19 + 1
 0: 20 = 20 + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setup the resulting list starting with the total sum and progressively extend it reducing the last element by values in the original list:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]


r = [sum(ls)]
r.extend(r[-1]-n for n in ls)

print(r)
# [21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6, 0]
```

Or, using itertools, accumulate the sum backwards and reverse the result:

```
from itertools import accumulate

r = [*accumulate([0]+ls[::-1])][::-1]

print(r)
# [21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6, 0]
```