# Last element in every bin defined by 'step' in range

Tags: python, binning

When we use `range(start, stop, step)` it returns every first element in every bin defined by step.

For example,

```
list(range(1, 10, 5))
```

returns

```
[1, 6]
```

But how can i get the last elements from every bin defined by step?
I expect to get

```
[5, 10]
```

Comment: `list(range(5, 11, 5))`

Comment: `list(range(0+5, 10+1, 5))`
5 is the step size here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print a list in reverse order with range()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286365/print-a-list-in-reverse-order-with-range)

Comment: Why are you using `range`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply swap the values in the range function to get the reverse like so:

```
print(list(range(10, 0, -5)))
```

This returns:

```
[10, 5]
```

You could do `list(range(10, 0, -5))[::-1]` to get `[5, 10]`.

---

Or you could write your own generator function like so:

```
def range_end(start, end, step):
    i = end

    while i > start:
        yield i
        i -= step

print(list(range_end(1, 10, 5)))
```

This returns:

```
[10, 5]
```

---

And if you want to have it reversed simply do:

```
print(list(range_end(1, 10, 5))[::-1])
```

This returns:

```
[5, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the values of your `range` function.

Using

```py
list(range(5, 11, 5))
```

You can get your desired result.

### Explanation

The `range` function takes up to `3` arguments: `start`, `end` and `step` and will return a range object (which you can convert to a list).

- The created list (using `list(...)`) will start with the value you set as the `start` argument in your `range` call.
- The argument `end` is the element on which the list stops, but it is **NOT** included in the list.
- `step` is self-explanatory I think