# python - start from a number and then subtract x in a for

Tags: python

I have a code like this

```
for x in range(1,20):
    print(x)
```

it works perfectly, but when I want to start from the end like => 60 to 1 i tried this first

```
for x in range(20,1):
    print(x)
```

but it prints nothing!
also, I tried this,

```
for x in range(1,20):
    count = 20
    count -= 1
    print(count)
```

but -= 1 only printed twenty samples of 19.
any help?

Comment: Did you try `range(20, 0, -1)`?

Comment: I just tried this, and it works! :) thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the first statement INSIDE your for loop (count =20). Think about what is happening to count every time the for loop increments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print a list in reverse order with range()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286365/print-a-list-in-reverse-order-with-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First answer:**
Use [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) built-in function whit negative step:

```
for x in range(20, 1, -1):
    print(x)
```

**Second answer:**
You have to declare the `count` variable outside the for loop, otherwise it will be initialized to 20 each loop, and then subtracting 1 will always make 19 for each loop.

```
count = 20
for x in range(1,20):
    count -= 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: This works, but the OP needs to see what they are doing in the for loop that is causing the 19s to repeat

Answer (score 1):

@Massifox already pointed out the -1 step but I can add more context. The optional third parameter in range() is step. If you did `range(1, 20, 2)` it would print `2, 4, 6, ..., 18` because you specified steps of 2.

For your example, you started 20, and incremented until you hit 1, but that will never happen, so nothing gets printed, so you specify a step of -1 like `range(20, 1, -1)`, so that it will step backwards each iteration printing `20, 19, ..., 2` (second parameter is exclusive).

When you tried this

```
for x in range(1,20):
    count = 20
    count -= 1
    print(count)
```

You created a temp variable named count, initialized to 20, subtracted one from it, and then printed it, and the result was the 19's you were getting. Everything inside the for loop will be a temporary variable and cannot affect the iteration of the for loop. LMK if this is too verbose.