# Execution doesn't go on the next fuction

Tags: python, function

I'm stuck with an exercise which asks me to design a door mat of `NxM` size, in which `N` is *an odd number* and `M` is *equal to `N*3`*, in the way you can see [*there*](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/designer-door-mat/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) with the full explanation of the exercise.

To do that I've written the following code:

```py
door_mat_length = int(input())
door_mat_width = door_mat_length * 3
string = '.|.'
welcome = 'WELCOME'

for i in range(1, int((door_mat_length + 1) / 2)):
    string_multiplier = string * (i + (i - 1))
    print(string_multiplier.center(door_mat_width, '-')) 

print(welcome.center(door_mat_width, '-'))

for i in range(int((door_mat_length + 1) / 2), 1):
    string_multiplier = string * (i + (i - 1))
    print(string_multiplier.center(door_mat_width, '-'))
```

But the program stops at the print command in the middle, without iterating over the next fuction. How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it throw any exception? Or just exit with `0` exit code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decreasing for loops in Python impossible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294082/decreasing-for-loops-in-python-impossible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to this :

```
door_mat_length = int(input())
door_mat_width = door_mat_length * 3
string = '.|.'
welcome = 'WELCOME'

for i in range(1, int((door_mat_length + 1) / 2)):
    string_multiplier = string * (i + (i - 1))
    print(string_multiplier.center(door_mat_width, '-'))

print(welcome.center(door_mat_width, '-'))

for i in reversed(range(1,int((door_mat_length + 1) / 2) )):
    string_multiplier = string * (i + (i - 1))
    print(string_multiplier.center(door_mat_width, '-'))
```

input: 10

output:

```
-------------.|.--------------
----------.|..|..|.-----------
-------.|..|..|..|..|.--------
----.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.-----
-----------WELCOME------------
----.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.-----
-------.|..|..|..|..|.--------
----------.|..|..|.-----------
-------------.|.--------------
```

Comment: Thanks! From what I've understood, I forgot to insert a step value

Answer (score 1):

range step is 1 in default.

[Python range doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)

In the document, it says `For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.` and `For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and r[i] > stop.` So your second for loop range return a empty range.

Like

```
for i in range(5, 1):
    print(i)
```

don't print anything. To solve this, you must pass a negative step to make it goes down. Like:

```
for i in range(5, 1, -1):
    print(i)
```

It prints

```
5
4
3
2
```

So if you want to use range to go down, make sure you pass a step value.

```
for i in range(int((door_mat_length + 1) / 2) - 1, 0, -1):
```

Comment: Thank you! I've understood what the problem was